# I need help on right triangles

Tags: geometry, triangles

With the premise that the length of a right triangle's hypotenuse is 5.822153, what is the length of its two other sides such that if the triangle's hypotenuse were its base, then the height of the triangle will be 1.987424?

Comment: You have two conditions that the legs of the right triangle must satisfy.  First is the Pythagorean relation to the hypotenuse. Second is the area of the right triangle, given by the height of the triangle over the hypotenuse.

Comment: There are always three sides you can choice as base.  If the legs are a and b the area is $\frac 12 ab $.  If you take the hypotenuse as base the area is $\frac 12 5.8*1.9=\frac 12ab $. And of course $a^2+b^2=5..8^2$.  That's enough to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

It can easily be proved using Similarity of Triangles that $h^2 = x(c-x)$.

You have the value of $h$ and $c$. Solve the resulting quadratic to get $x$ and apply Pythagoras Theorem to get the two sides of the triangle.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @hardmath's comment, if you let the catheti (perpendicular sides) have lengths $a$ and $b$ and the hypotenuse $c$ and height (perpendicular to hypotenuse) $h$, you get the system of two equations:

$\frac 12 ab = \frac 12 ch$ (based on equal areas computed two different ways)

$a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ (based on Pythagoras' theorem)

Putting $b^2 = c^2 - a^2$ and squaring the first equation, you get:

$a^2(c^2 - a^2) = c^2h^2$

Rearranging, you get a quartic in $a$ (which is a quadratic in $a^2$):

$(a^2)^2 - c^2\cdot a^2 + c^2h^2 = 0$

and you can solve that for $a^2$, from which you can compute $a$.